# When does the community protect the question?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

I didn't find any help related to this topic. How does the community protect a question? What is the logic behind that? Here is an example question:

> protected by Community♦ 58 mins ago
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site.

*[Display of "Not visible individually" for a simple product in mini cart in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111057/magento-2-display-not-visible-individually-simple-product-in-mini-cart)*

Comment: @gnat i don't see that question is much older and not so much view that stuck in mind may be some other reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question attracts a lot of spam answers then when they're deleted the question automatically gets protected, as it's clearly been identified as a target for spammers for whatever reason.

Moderators and users with the [Protect Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege can also protect questions, but that's a manual process. Community does it as a result of posts getting flagged and deleted.